# Permanent fixed IDE-like layout for Vim

Tags: layout, vim, ide

I'm just gettings started with gVim and I'm trying to get a working basis to be productive with.

I've done the basic configuration and installed some plugins:

- SnipMate
- MiniBufExpl
- TagList
- Surround
- VimLatex

I've read the tutorials "vimtutor" on how to perform basic operations in vim, and some basics about netrw. What I'm trying to achieve now is to get Vim to behave like an IDE. So once I Open vim I'd like to automatically get a certain screen setup like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                      MiniBufExpl                          |
| [1: Tab1][2: Tab2][3: Tab3]...                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| NetRw |         File contents as tabs           | TagList |
|       |                                         |         |
|       |                                         |         |
   ...                     ...                        ...   
|       |                                         |         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                  Compiler/Debug messages                  |
|                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**My Questions for the moment are:**

1. How do I get Vim to memorize such a layout once it is set? (I'm not
   good with scripting Vim yet, and setting up the layout manually
   using the "split" commands every time is kind of inconvenient).
2. How can I achieve files to be opened *always* in the center area of
   the layout no matter if I use the ":open" command, netrw or any
   other way to open a file?

I might consider to use NerdTree instead of Netrw if there are good reasons. The reason why I decided to try to stick with Netrw is, that it would be just nice to not rely on too many plugins, so I learn to fluently work on systems with basic Vim installations.

Comment: [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) is a more powerful variation on the snippets idea. It allows Python code to be used in snippets. Additionally, I'd advise you to look at the [syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) plugin. And [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) if you're using git.

Comment: Thanks for the tips I'll check out UltiSnips and see if it does a better job than SnipMate (which is already doing a pretty good job IMO). Syntastic seems awesome so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably make Vim *look* like an IDE (if you squint long enough) but you will never turn it into an IDE. Vim is a text editor with a philosophy of its own: embrace it and you'll rip many benefits, ignore it and… you won't.

Anyway…

- NERDTree is a lot closer to your standard file explorer pane than Netrw: if you *really* need a file explorer pane always open, NERDTree is your only realistic option. However, such tools are actually worthless (they are used too rarely to justify the wasted space) so you should probably explore other ways. This is what you have to do when you want to open another file with an "always on" NERDTree and with the most common usage of netrw:

  ```
  NERDTree                         Netrw

  switch to the NERDTree window    open netrw
  navigate to/search for the file  navigate to/search for the file
  hit a key to open the file       hit a key to open the file
  ```

  Basically, you have the same amount of work for the same result, but the netrw way doesn't waste a single cell on your screen. Note that you can use NERDTree that way, too.

  And the same principle applies to MiniBufExplorer, obviously.
- Tabs in Vim don't work like tabs in other editors at all and you *can't* force them to do so. Documents are loaded into buffers and that's what you want to manipulate, not tabs, at least until you understand the difference. See `:help usr_07.txt`, `:help tabpage` and `:help buffers`.
- You don't need the quickfix window to be "always on" either: see `:help quickfix`.

To answer your two questions:

1. You can save a layout with the `:mksession` command, you can read all about it with `:help :mksession`.
2. You can't without a lot of effort and self control. If you go with NERDTree you'll have to go with NERDTree all the way. And `:open` doesn't do what you think it does.

In Vim, the most efficient layout may very well be

```
+------------------+
| the current      |
| buffer           |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

Comment: Okay probably I didn't grasp the philosophy behind vim yet. My interest into learning it is because: 1. the possibilities to move and edit quickly using the shortcuts, 2. the good regular expression support, 3. the possibility to work on limited systems sometimes I have to stick with my netbook and its no fun at all to work with an IDE on an Atom machine with 1024x600 resolution. Anyhow I still need to find a way to open projects and switch between the files quickly, we're talking about large projects multiple 100 files. I cant open them all and I need an overview to jump between them quickly.

Comment: 1. You can't beat Vim on that front. 2. Idem. 3. Yes, Vim is not as wasteful as your typical IDE (screen estate and resources) but the more you try to turn it into an IDE the less this advantage will be evident. As for opening files, you can use `:Ex`, `:Rex` and friends, or `:find`, `:e` and friends with tab-completion. Switching buffers is also very easy with `:b <tab>` and `:bn`, `:bp`. The IDE paradigm is an obstacle, here, not a worthy goal.

Comment: With `let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1`, I can use NERDTree without it ever being a problem. BufExplorer has that behaviour by default. While I agree they are not really necessary, "worthless" is going a bit far: I use `:e file` quite a bit, but NERDTree gives me a nice overview when I need it. However, I totally agree that making Vim look like a traditional IDE is a losing proposition.

Comment: @Amadan, you can have that behavior without installing a third-party plugin.

Comment: Yes. But I like NERDTree more than `:Sex`.

Comment: I stumbled upon the [eclim plugin](http://eclim.org/) for vim, while this might provide a solution pretty close to what I was asking for, the tenor of the majority seems to be that this plugin is doing it all wrong.

Comment: @norritt, what tenor and what majority?

Comment: The majority meaning you, Amadan and Ingo seem to agree that vim shouldn't be IDEified. This opinion is what I described as general tenor. So using eclim might be the best answer to my above question but the discussion here raises a new question for me: "Should I do what I intended to do when I asked the question above" or more precise "Is it a bad idea to IDEify vim, and what are the alternatives". Not IDEifying vim leaves a lot of convenience issues unsolved for me, which might just be a result of being a beginner. Still its hard to get acquainted to a software you can't use productively...

Comment: Many people use Vim productively, even people who IDEified it to death. My *opinion* (based on my short experience) is that Vim should be used as what it is, a text editor, and that you should use an IDE if you want IDE features.

Answer (score 0):

For GVIM, you may get a fixed layout with a little bit of effort (but some commands / plugins may still disrupt it, so it will never be fully like an IDE), but you're missing out on using (at least occasionally, e.g. over SSH) terminal Vim (as terminals often occupy much less space, maybe just 80x25 characters).

As romainl has argued, it's a bad idea to copy the look and features of an IDE just because one "is used to it". So, instead of a fixed layout, you're much better served by toggling individual functions (like the file tree or the quickfix list) only on demand, via quick and short custom mappings.